# What is this file: .terraform.tfstate.lock.info?

Tags: terraform

Any light on what this Terraform file is:

```
.terraform.tfstate.lock.info
```

Comment: Isn't that the lock file used to avoid concurrent tf applies?

Comment: I saw this file while running `terraform destory` and it removed after finished

Answer (score 2):

The info files store the [state locking](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/locking.html) metadata. The metadata contains the lock ID, which is required to unlock the state ([source](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/25f6e610476859a6a132b1f08dcea2540fef571b/state/state.go#L82))